# Is there any way to add RawHTML in form elements on Sitecore sxa xm?

Tags: sxa, sitecore-forms

Im not getting the RawHTML element in the form element section.
[image: Image for reference]

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore provides you `Text Element` OOTB to add Text using the `Text Field` where you can choose the HTML tag to put your text like below.

[image]

But if you want to add HTML then you need to create a custom field called `Rich Text Field` with Sitecore Form.

For you this you can refer to this article to create a custom field that will allow you to add HTML.

https://pushpaganan.home.blog/2020/02/06/adding-a-custom-rich-text-field-to-sitecore-forms/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @sumit-bhatia

Comment: @AnoopKumar Please accept the answer if the solution works for you. This will help other folks. Thanks. Refer to this. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer